# SwiftUI Chart y-axis data does not align properly when using dates

Tags: swift, swiftui, charts, swiftui-charts

I created a Line Chart in SwiftUI.

Drawing a Chart wasn't a problem. But I don't know why data doesn't align with y-axis label and grid line. The data is plotted slightly below.

[image]

It's just basic code. So I don't have anything to try some.

Is just SwiftUI Bug?

Does anyone know about this issue?

**This is the whole code**

```
import SwiftUI
import Charts

struct Time {
    let date: String
    let time: String
}

struct ChartsView: View {
    
    @State var timeData: [Time] = [
        .init(date: "2023-12-01", time: "07:50:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-02", time: "08:00:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-03", time: "08:10:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-04", time: "08:00:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-05", time: "08:00:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-06", time: "07:50:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-07", time: "08:00:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-08", time: "07:50:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-09", time: "08:10:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-10", time: "08:10:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-11", time: "08:10:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-12", time: "08:10:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-13", time: "07:50:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-14", time: "08:10:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-15", time: "07:50:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-16", time: "07:50:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-17", time: "08:00:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-18", time: "08:00:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-19", time: "08:00:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-20", time: "08:00:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-21", time: "08:00:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-22", time: "08:10:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-23", time: "08:00:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-24", time: "08:00:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-25", time: "08:00:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-26", time: "07:50:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-27", time: "08:00:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-28", time: "08:00:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-29", time: "08:00:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-30", time: "08:10:00"),
        .init(date: "2023-12-31", time: "07:50:00")
    ]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack(alignment: .bottom, content: {
            Chart {
                ForEach(timeData, id: \.date) {
                    LineMark(x: .value("x", $0.date.dateYYYYMMdd ?? Date(), unit: .day), 
                             y: .value("y", $0.time.dateHHmmss ?? Date(), unit: .minute))
                        .foregroundStyle(.red.opacity(0.3))
                        .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1))
                        .symbol {
                            Circle()
                                .fill(.red)
                                .frame(width: 4)
                        }
                    RuleMark(y: .value("y", "08:08:00".dateHHmmss ?? Date(), unit: .minute))
                }
            }
            .frame(height: 165)
            .padding(24)
        })        
    }
}

extension String {
    var dateYYYYMMdd: Date? {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "YYYY-MM-dd"
        return formatter.date(from: self)
    }
    
    var dateHHmmss: Date? {
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "HH:mm:ss"
        return formatter.date(from: self)
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need `unit: .minute` for anything? If not, you should just remove it.

Comment: @Sweeper If I remove it, chart doesn't work. After posting this, I just found the solution(?). Use ```unit: .second```. Then data aligned. I don't know why. Datas second is all zero. So I chose ```.minute```. Anyway, ```.second``` works

Comment: Well the chart still works for me. How exactly does it "not work"? `unit:` basically centers your value between two adjacent `unit`s. For example, `unit: .minute` would put `08:10` at `08:10:30` since that is between `08:10` and `08:11`.

Comment: I'm using Preview in Xcode. And if I remove ```unit:```, the preview crashed. So I said it's not work. But there may be something wrong in my code. Also I didn't know that unit centers value and it made ```08:10:30```.  Thank you for your advice.

Comment: Note it is very inefficient to re-initialize date formatters like that. You should store a single instance and re-use it.

Comment: I cannot reproduce it on preview either. Read the console output to see what the error is, and/or run it on the simulator.

Comment: @shim Yeah, I know what you mean. This is sample model and I'm using different model in real project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove `unit: .minute` from the y axis' value.

The `unit:` plots the value in the half way point between two consecutive units that you specify. For example, `unit: .minute` would put 08:10 at 08:10:30, because that is the half way point between 08:10 and 08:11.

[image]

This is produced by 3 rule marks:

```
RuleMark(y: .value("y", "08:08:00".dateHHmmss ?? Date()))
    .foregroundStyle(.red)
RuleMark(y: .value("y", "08:08:00".dateHHmmss ?? Date(), unit: .minute))
    .foregroundStyle(.green)
RuleMark(y: .value("y", "08:09:00".dateHHmmss ?? Date()))
    .foregroundStyle(.blue)
```

---

While I can't think of a good reason to use `unit:` in line graphs, it is very useful when doing bar charts. `BarMark`s determine how wide the bar should be, then data is plotted in the centre point of the bar. If you combine this with axis labels centred between the grid lines of each unit, the axis labels would be at the bottom centres of the bars.

[image]

Code:

```
Chart {
    ForEach(data, id: \.date) {
        BarMark(x: .value("x", $0.date, unit: .day),
                y: .value("y", $0.y))
            .foregroundStyle(.red.opacity(0.3))
    }
}
.chartXAxis(content: {
    AxisMarks(values: AxisMarkValues.stride(by: .day)) { _ in
        AxisGridLine()
        AxisValueLabel(format: .dateTime.month().day(), centered: true)
    }
})
```